# IntelliJ cannot resolve symbol in build.sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

IntelliJ IDEA 15 is reporting an unresolved symbol for my project definition in my `build.sbt` file

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

It's reporting an error with `project` and `in`.

```
Cannot resolve symbol project.
Cannot resolve symbol in.
```

Everything else resolves perfectly and the project is otherwise all set up, sbt builds fine, activator runs fine.

Comment: Please post the entire error message. Do you get the same if you run sbt from a terminal? It is possible that the error is "old", i.e. from IntelliJ IDEA parsing your incomplete build file while you were writing it.

Comment: Are you using Intellij 15.0.1? If yes, it is Intellij bug.

Comment: @LuongBaLinh Checked jetbrains error tracker and it is indeed, is also reported and assigned just not fixed yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix this issue, I imported: `import sbt.project` on top of my `build.sbt`

I am working with IntelliJ IDEA 16 EAP

Comment: Works in combination with a bunch of iterations of: PC restarts, Intellij restarts, removing .idea folder and reloading & clearing metadata, ... Been having this issue of and on for years and the cause still eludes me.

Answer (score 21):

In my case, after upgrading Intellij forgot that the project was a Scala project.

Delete `.idea/` and import the project to fix this.

Comment: Worked for me. I had the same problem but I did not update intellij

Comment: Worked for me tooooo

Answer (score 5):

I looked on jetbrains' error tracker and found this is a known bug.

> "Cannot resolve symbol project" in build.sbt

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9512

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when when the "external library" referenced was a different version than the one stated in the `build.sbt` file. Specifically:

External Libraries -> `SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.1`

build.sbt -> `scalaVersion := "2.12.2"`

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with `http` references in my `~/sbt/repositories` file. When I changed this to `https` all was well.

```
typesafe-releases: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases
typesafe-ivy-releasez: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```