# Disabling analysis build.sbt in IntelliJ Scala plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I use IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.01, Scala plugin 3.0.0.
The issue is that IntellJ always try to analyze the file to show error messages.

[image]
[image]

How can I disable the analysis by treating the build.sbt as a text file? I'm bothered to see the error keep prompting me to get the namespace for "version" variable.

Comment: Why do you need that? IntelliJ Idea perfectly works with `.sbt` and should parse it correctly. If it does not - it means that you have something configured wrong

Comment: @Archeg: Well, you may be right, but I'm bothered to see the error prompting to get the namespace for "version" variable.

Comment: I do not see any error with `version` in the same setup. Maybe you should look at it with another angle. I'd assume that if IntelliJ Idea cannot parse `.sbt` you will have some other problems soon, like Idea not able to run application, using wrong `sbt` or something else. It's just weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this is a bug in IntelliJ (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9512). 
Also references:

- [IntelliJ cannot resolve symbol in build.sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245991/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-in-build-sbt)
- [SBT + Idea 13 => Cannot resolve symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845862/sbt-idea-13-cannot-resolve-symbol)

For temporary fix not to see the nagging error message:

In file type configuration, .sbt is associated with sbt. I removed the association to remove the errors and warnings.

[image]

I could associate the .sbt file type to normal text file.

[image]